# can't start biber(bibLaTex Compiler), although it is successful installed (fedora21)

Tags: yum, rpm, bibtex, fedora-21, texlive

**solved**

Hey,
i installed texlive-biblatex* , but strangly i cant start it, using "biber".

```
 $ biber
bash: biber: Befehl nicht gefunden...
```

Also i cant access the manpage for bibLaTeX:

```
$ man biblatex
Kein Handbucheintrag für biblatex vorhanden
```

but for e.g. bibTeX i can.

```
$ man bibtex
```

Additionaly, cd /usr/bin/ && ls | grep bib shows bibtex, but not biber or anything else.

```
$ cd /usr/bin/
$ ls | grep bib
bibtex
$
```

But yum info texlive-biblatex shows, that it is successful installed.

```
 $ yum info texlive-biblatex
Geladene Plugins: langpacks
rpmfusion-free                                                                                                                                                          470/470
rpmfusion-nonfree                                                                                                                                                       178/178
virtualbox                                                                                                                                                                12/12
Installierte Pakete
Name       : texlive-biblatex
Architektur : noarch
Epoche             :4
Version    : svn32245.2.8a
Ausgabe    : 3.1.fc21
Größe : 1.7 M
Quelle      : installed
Aus Quelle  : updates
Zusammenfassung: Bibliographies in LaTeX using BibTeX for sorting only
URL        : http://tug.org/texlive/
Lizenz      : LPPL
Beschreibung: [...]
            : 
            : date: 2013-11-24 17:41:16 +0100
```

I use fedora 21.

any ideas?

regards

EDIT: it is solved, biber isnt included in texlatex-biblatex, i had to install it myself:

```
sudo  wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/biber.repo https://copr.fedoraproject.org/coprs/cbm/Biber/repo/fedora-21/cbm-Biber-fedora-21.repo
sudo yum install biber
```

**or:**

```
sudo yum install dnf-plugin-copr
sudo dnf copr enable cbm/Biber
sudo yum install biber
```